# Draw more than one group of lines in MKMapView using MKPolyline

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, polyline

I'm using this code to draw one group of lines:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D points[[routes count]];
for(int i = 0; i < self.routes.count; i++)
{
    CLLocation* location = [self.routes objectAtIndex:i];
    points[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate
                                             .longitude);
}
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: points count: [routes count]];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect: [self.routeLine boundingMapRect] animated: YES];
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

And it's working for one group of lines that comes from `NSArray *routes`, but now I need more than one group of lines, for example a `NSMutableArray *routes = { NSArray with routes , NSArray with other group like first example , another array }` probably like this:

```
int sumaCount = [a1 count] + [a2 count] + [a3 count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D puntitos[sumaCount];
int c = 0;
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
{
    for (CLLocation *cada in array)
    {
        puntitos[c] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cada.coordinate.latitude, cada.coordinate.longitude);
        c++;
    }
    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: puntitos count: sumaCount];
    [self.mapView addOverlay: self.routeLine];
}
```

but I get this exception:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
 -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is happening from the code shown?  Do you want each group to be a separate overlay or should they be connected as one line?

Comment: Well @AnnaKarenina, Each group of lines, are not connected, only the group of lines. I mean, first group probably it's a polygon, but the next group an square but in another place in the MKMapView, so I guessed that It's other overlay, but yes, I debugged and comes from that code... but no explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues: The bugs in your supplied code and the exception.

**Code bugs**

You are adding the overlay for all `sumaCount` points before you finishing the building of the `puntitos` structure (e.g. the first time `addOverlay` is called, you have only added `[a1 count]` points). You're also assuming that `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` are all of the items in `rutas`. If you want them connected, you should:

- Take the `addOverlay` out of the loop; and
- Don't use `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`, but rather iterated through `rutas` to get the `sumaCount`

Thus, if you really wanted to join the three groups of lines together, you would:

```
int sumaCount = 0;
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
    sumaCount += [array count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D puntitos[sumaCount];

int c = 0;
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
{
    for (CLLocation *cada in array)
    {
        puntitos[c] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cada.coordinate.latitude, cada.coordinate.longitude);
        c++;
    }
}

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: puntitos count: sumaCount];
[self.mapView addOverlay: self.routeLine];
```

If you're dealing with three separate groups of lines, you should:

```
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
{
    int sumaCount = [array count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D puntitos[sumaCount];

    int c = 0;
    for (CLLocation *cada in array)
    {
        puntitos[c] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cada.coordinate.latitude, cada.coordinate.longitude);
        c++;
    }
    MKPolyline routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: puntitos count: c];
    [self.mapView addOverlay: routeLine];
}
```

Note in this latter example, I'm not using your `MKPolyline` property, but a local var. If you need to keep an array of these `MKPolyline` objects, just go ahead and do that, but for the purposes of the above code, you don't need it. Frankly, in the first example, I'd probably be inclined to you a local `MKPolyline` variable, too. Why keep it in a class property?!?

**Exception**

The above fixes the bugs in your listed code, but your exception points to yet another issue. It could be your code (since your first attempt to create the `MKPolyline` is using `sumaCount` points but have only set a few of them). But the problem may reset elsewhere, too, because the exception is not what you expect from your code's bugs. Are you doing any regular expression matching elsewhere in your code? If you're convinced that the issue is in the code, itself, you can

```
NSLog(@"rutas=%@", rutas);
```

Personally, I'd be surprised if the regex problem was caused by this, but the code in your original question could definitely cause some unexpected problems. I'd fix the code, and see if your exception still occurs. If it does, add this `rutas` log statement, but better, search for `NSRegularExpression` in your project and see where you might be using that. You can also [turn on exception breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) (just turn it on for all exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand now my bugs, and I'm not using regular expressions, but I think it was the wrong way to use `sumaCount`, tomorrow I will select the answer, and both are pretty good, thank you.

Comment: Hey @Rob that's working 100% with no crashes I appreciate your help, really. But I think I have to solve a "new" problem, I need before do that, to delete the "old" overlay before drawing new points. that's why I used `self.routeLine`, but I will figure out  by myself and I think at the moment how to. Thanks.

Comment: @rokimoki Very good. If you get stumped on how to remove the previous overlays, let us know. But you definitely don't need to keep `self.routeLine` around for that purpose.

Comment: Mmh, why I can't have self.routeLine? well actually I did a NSMutableArray with all routeLine added in the overlay, then if need I remove all overlay and clean the array.

Comment: @rokimoki You _can_ if you want. I'm just suggesting that you apply Ockham's razor and ask if you _need_ to. If you need it, then by all means, do so. But it's just an opportunity to get your personal array of `MKPolyline` and the `MKMapView` array of `overlays` out of sync. `MKMapView` provides all sorts of methods of maintaining `overlays` (e.g. `addOverlay`, `addOverlays`, `removeOverlay`, `removeAllOverlays`). Can you accomplish what you want using the `MKMapView` property `overlays` and all of the associated methods? If not, then create your own array and keep the two in sync.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Rob, but I wonder that probabbly I need it but with more experience I will realize that I will not need it, at the moment I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If that error really is coming from the code shown, you may be using a deallocated instance of some variable.

If you are going to add multiple overlays at once, you should stop using the `routeLine` and `routeLineView` properties which can only hold a reference to one at a time.

Declare and create an `MKPolyline` and `MKPolylineView` variable locally.

The main issue with the second section of code is that it calls `addOverlay` for each `array` in `rutas` but the `puntitos` array and `sumaCount` keep getting accumulated with values from *all* the `array` objects (eg. overlay 1 is just the first `array`, overlay 2 is a combination of first and second `array`, etc).

If you want a separate overlay for each `array` in `rutas`, `puntitos` and `sumaCount` should be declared and initialized for *each* `array` (ie. put inside the first for-loop).  Following is an example:

```
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
{
    int sumaCount = [array count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D puntitos[sumaCount];
    int c = 0;

    for (CLLocation *cada in array)
    {
        puntitos[c] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cada.coordinate.latitude, cada.coordinate.longitude);
        c++;
    }

    MKPolyline *arrayLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: puntitos count: sumaCount];
    [self.mapView addOverlay: arrayLine];
}
```

If instead you want a single overlay that combines all `array` objects, put the `MKPolyline` creation and `addOverlay` *after* the main for-loop (and keep the declaration and initialization of `puntitos` and `sumaCount` *before* the main for-loop).  For example:

```
int sumaCount = 0;
CLLocationCoordinate2D puntitos[sumaCount];
int c = 0;
for (NSArray *array in rutas)
{
    sumaCount = sumaCount + [array count];

    for (CLLocation *cada in array)
    {
        puntitos[c] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cada.coordinate.latitude, cada.coordinate.longitude);
        c++;
    }
}

MKPolyline *rutasLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates: puntitos count: sumaCount];
[self.mapView addOverlay: rutasLine];
```

In `viewForAnnotation`, remember to change the code to *not* use `routeLine` and `routeLineView` (you should just get rid of these to avoid confusion).  For example:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *pv = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay] autorelease];
      //remove autorelease if not using ARC

    pv.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    pv.lineWidth = 5;

    return pv;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick answer I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Your code helped me @AnnaKarenina, but I think @Rob's helped me a little bit more, but the clarification of the `- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay` helped me to have each group of lines with different colors =) thanks!